# Data Transformation in R - Dummies

Tags: r

I want to work with 4 national football teams (England, Belgium, Germany and France) and n dates

```
Date        Matches
16.03       England X Brazil
16.03       Belgium X Argentina
16.03       Chile X Japan
16.03       Uruguay X Germany
16.03       Italy x France
17.03       South Korea X India
17.03       Germany X France
17.03       Poland  X Belgium
17.03       Colombia X Russia
18.03       South Africa X Mexico
18.03       China X Japon
18.03       Brazil X Venezuela
...          ...
```

DESIRED DATAFRAME with dummies. When **dummy = 1** the team played. When **dummy = 0** the team didnt played (in the day). Important: Only one date per row.

```
Date   Dummy_england   Dummy_belgium    Dummy_germany    Dummy_France
16.03  1               1                1                1
17.03  0               1                1                1
18.03  0               0                0                0
```

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/) methods.

1. Extract the selected team from each row of 'Matches' with [`str_extract`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_extract)
2. Keep only the rows where there is a match i.e. NA rows are removed with `filter`
3. Use [`pivot_wider`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html) to reshape from long to 'wide' after `select`ing the columns of interest - specify the `values_fn` as `length` and `values_fill` as 0 to change the default `NA` to 0

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(team = str_c('Dummy_', str_extract(Matches, 
       regex('England|Belgium|Germany|France', ignore_case = TRUE)))) %>%
   filter(complete.cases(team)) %>%
   select(-Matches) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = team, values_from = team,  
          values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
   Date Dummy_England Dummy_Belgium Dummy_Germany Dummy_France
  <dbl>         <int>         <int>         <int>        <int>
1  16.0             1             1             1            1
2  17.0             0             1             1            0
```

---

If we want to keep the 'Date' where there are no matches, use `complete`

```
df1 %>%
   mutate(team = str_c('Dummy_', str_extract(Matches, 
    regex('England|Belgium|Germany|France', ignore_case = TRUE)))) %>%
   filter(complete.cases(team)) %>%
   select(-Matches) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = team, values_from = team, 
        values_fn = length, values_fill = 0) %>% 
   complete(Date = unique(df1$Date), fill = list(Dummy_England = 0,
         Dummy_Belgium = 0, Dummy_Germany = 0, Dummy_France = 0))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
   Date Dummy_England Dummy_Belgium Dummy_Germany Dummy_France
  <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>        <dbl>
1  16.0             1             1             1            1
2  17.0             0             1             1            0
3  18.0             0             0             0            0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c(16.03, 16.03, 16.03, 16.03, 16.03, 17.03, 
17.03, 17.03, 17.03, 18.03, 18.03, 18.03), Matches = c("England X Brazil", 
"Belgium X Argentina", "Chile X Japan", "Uruguay X Germany", 
"Italy x France", "South Korea X India", "Germany X France", 
"Poland  X Belgium", "Colombia X Russia", "South Africa X Mexico", 
"China X Japon", "Brazil X Venezuela")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dummy_england <- tapply(Matches, Date, function(x) {
                      grepl("England", paste(x, collapse = ''))*1
                })
```

Comment: Not a very general solution. The OP would still have to call this function many times with different arguments.